# What research expenses to request for early career fellowship?

Tags: research-process, funding

I'm applying for an early career fellowship in the UK. The fellowship has a budget of up to £6k per year for research expenses to further the fellow's research activities, which must be requested upfront. Other than travel to conferences, small equipment, and perhaps organising a workshop, does anyone have any good ideas about what this money might be spent on?

Comment: Software licenses and open access fees maybe? Also don't forget money to invite people to come to visit you.

Comment: Books? At least in some fields, we still read those old musty things. :)

Comment: If you plan to participate one or two international conferences than is is not that of a big money. Also, depending on regulations you may be able to get a computer/laptop + some software you need for your work.

Answer (score 1):

The following list is very subject dependent, but some items you might want to include are:

- High Performance Computing time (e.g. comp-sci, physics, maths, chemistry etc)
- Lab or equipment hire costs
- Research technician time (i.e someone who might help acquire data or do some other more routine tasks)
- The all-encompassing "computer-consumables" (that covers quite a lot)